# Finding a word in given text using nested and/or along with in/not in operators

Tags: python, string, if-statement, string-matching

Hi i have a string and i am trying to print some message when a certain condition found.
Code i am using -

```
text = """The nearest paid public fire department 24/7 is located 1km"""

if ((("public" in text.lower()) or ("Public" in text.lower()))
    and (("fire department" in text.lower()))
    and (("full time" not in text.lower()) or ("full-time" not in text.lower()) or ("24/7" not in text.lower()))):
     print("Keyword not present in text")
else:
     print("Keyword present")

Output - Keyword not present in text
```

The output is wrong because 24/7 is present in the text and ideally it should print "Keyword present".

I can't split the sentence and then try looking for words because certain words i want to find as it is mentioned. For example "fire department".

Can you please suggest where i am going wrong.

Comment: Plese read about ```and``` and ```or```.

Comment: `"Public" in text.lower()` will always return False

Comment: @Sujay it is in the string...

Comment: Yeah. I saw it? The doesn't load for me quite a few times

Comment: ```("full time" not in text.lower())``` There is no ```full time``` in the text. So it will evaluate to True even if ```24/7``` is present/not as you are using ```or```. That's the reason you are getting ```Keyword not present in text```.

Answer (score 0):

```py
text = """The nearest full-time full time paid public fire department 24/7 is located 1km"""

expected = ["public", "fire department", "24/7"]

if any(s not in text.lower() for s in expected):
    print("Key words missing")
else:
    print("Keywords present")
```

A simpler way to achieve your result instead of having no many boolean comparisons.

If incase you want to validate few substring which shouldnt be part of the text

```py
expected = ["public", "fire department", "24/7"]
unexpected = ["full-time","full time"]

if any(s not in text.lower() for s in expected) or any(s in text.lower() for s in unexpected):
    print("Key words missing")
else:
    print("Keywords present")
```

The first part of the if condition validates that all expected substrings are present in the text.
The second part of the condition validates that none of the unexpected substrings are present in the text.